# Best way to share read intensive data across goroutines

Tags: go

I need to share a large tree (but for simplicity we can think it as a slice of strings) across multiple goroutines (http handlers). The tree is very rarely written, and only by one goroutine, but each http handler needs to read it.

Options I envisioned:

- Use a mutex: very expensive and high latency for my use case. Handlers will fight to get a lock even if 99% of the time is not needed, being a read mostly struct.
- Use channels: It's hard for me to imagine how I could use channels efficiently inside an http handler: it would need a good bit of boilerplate and it would copy the tree for each invocation, which is expensive.
- Use lazy pointers? At invocation the handler get a pointer to the current tree structure, new writes would happen by updating a new copy of the tree, and atomically updating the tree pointer. I should also keep the old tree available until all the running goroutines return. Seems a bit tricky to code.
- A mix of the last two? I could use channels to get the latest pointer to the tree, instead of the tree itself. Still a bit hard to imagine how would I write this down.

Is there any other way I'm not seeing? Any suggestion or tip?

Comment: ["A RWMutex is a reader/writer mutual exclusion lock. The lock can be held by an arbitrary number of readers or a single writer."](https://pkg.go.dev/sync#RWMutex)

Comment: thanks, if you post it as a reply I could mark it as an answer. Didn't know the difference between mutex and rwmutex. I would still be interested in a solution using atomics.

Comment: Actually the doc constains a better, mutex free answer, [here](https://pkg.go.dev/sync/atomic@master#example-Value-ReadMostly). If nobody answer with a better approach, I will use it as a reply.

Comment: How big is your map? The doc example you cite certainly works, but the write operation must copy & replace the entire map for each write. You need to weigh a mutex for each read operation vs. a large copy for each write operation.

Comment: @colm.anseo up to 16-32 mb, but is very seldomly written.

Comment: @Peter , after some benchmarking, your solution is 2 order of magnitude slower than lazy pointers. Situtation becomes exponentially worse at high thread count (above 32), or on Intel CPUs. Seems good for a prototype, but it's disastrous for production or hot path code.
More details:
https://gist.github.com/dim/152e6bf80e1384ea72e17ac717a5000a 
https://github.com/golang/go/issues/17973

Answer (score 0):

**Naive answer:**

The simplest approach is to use a RWLock as showed in the [official doc](https://pkg.go.dev/sync/atomic@master#example-Value-ReadMostly).
The problem is that after Spectre and Meltdown RWLock are significantly slower than atomics:

> Benchmark_RWMutex_parallel-6      66796699            17.96 ns/op
>
> Benchmark_Atomic_parallel-6       1000000000           0.5528 ns/op

The situation becomes exponentially worse with high thread count (above 32 threads) or intel CPUs. You can find more discussion about this [here](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/17973).

**Modern answer:**

[Here's](https://go.dev/play/p/HUDExbSXrFA) an example using atomics. It can still be improved by using pointers instead of structs, but it's a very good starting point.